# g++ -static causes memory leak (reported by mtrace)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, g++, static-libraries, mtrace

So I'm having a strange problem that I'm hoping someone can shed some light on... I have the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mcheck.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void *run(void *args)
{
  sleep(1);
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  mtrace();
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, run, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

And I compile I've compiled it in these 2 ways:

```
g++ -static program.cpp -lpthread
```

and

```
g++ program.cpp -ltpthread
```

When I look at the mtrace's output (mem.out in my case)

I see the following when i use the `-static` option, `mtrace` reports:

```
Memory Not freed:
__________________
   Address      Size   Caller
   0x085ac350   0x88   program.cpp:0
```

But when I exclude the `-static` option, `mtrace` reports the glorious:

```
No memory leaks.
```

So any ideas as to whats going on here?

Comment: Not sure what -static does but it might be that the staticly allocated stuff might be deallocated after mtrace reports the leak. I remember having the same stuff happen with _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

Comment: Sounds like a feature of mtrace, try Valgrind?

Comment: Why you have no any returns in you run function?

Comment: @KerrekSB - Psh you've never heard of the `int void` type? What a noob... also, I fixed it.

Comment: do you get the same result if you run valgrind?

Comment: Should be `extern "C" void* run(void* args)` and it still needs to return a NULL not to flirt with undefined behavior.

Comment: @LokiAstari and @ AndreOriani - Add `return NULL`

Comment: @LokiAstari - What does this do? I tried it, and it didn't resolve it.

Comment: @Andrew: Its not to solve your problem (that's why it is a comment). But pthreads is a C library thus only understands the C ABI. Since you are writing C++ code you must mark the callback for pthread_create as C function to make sure that the compiler generates run() with the correct calling convention. Otherwise you are just hopping that C++ and C use the same conventions for functions and this is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: @LokiAstari - Gotcha.  That makes senses.

Comment: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu 12.04) - no memory leaks, so I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @wonder.mice - Interesting... I'm running Arch 3.0

Comment: @Andrew Arch doesn't have versions. You're either up to date or outdated.

Comment: @rubenvb - True enough... I always put 3.0 because when I log on, it tells me 3.0.

Comment: @Andrew: I bet that's GNOME 3.0.

Comment: @rubenvb - You might be right... but I don't have GNOME or even xorg installed... I'm a purest... I love typing. Something about being infront of a dark terminal all day... I love it.

Comment: @Andrew you must be running an old Linux kernel then. Mine's already at 3.4.8 `:P`. Completely off-topic, but what the heck.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this with Fedora Core 17 (3.5.2-3.fc17.x86_64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recipe for reproducing this on my regular desktop Linux system (FC-17):

```
#include <mcheck.h>
#include <pthread.h>

extern "C" { static void *run(void *) { return 0; } }

int main() {
  mtrace();
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, 0, run, 0);
  pthread_join(thread, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ -g -static -pthread`. This is how I executed it to get the `mtrace` error:

```
$ MALLOC_TRACE=mt.txt mtrace ./a.out mt.txt

Memory not freed:
-----------------
           Address     Size     Caller
0x00000000011a9c90    0x110  at 0x43d7f9
```

I have a 64 bit system, so the size doesn't match. When I disassemble the address in `gdb`, it gives this:

```
(gdb) disass 0x43d7f9
Dump of assembler code for function _dl_allocate_tls:
   0x000000000043d7c0 <+0>:     mov    %rbx,-0x20(%rsp)
   0x000000000043d7c5 <+5>:     mov    %rbp,-0x18(%rsp)
...
   0x000000000043d7f4 <+52>:    callq  0x428150 <calloc>
   0x000000000043d7f9 <+57>:    test   %rax,%rax
   0x000000000043d7fc <+60>:    je     0x43d8e0 <_dl_allocate_tls+288>
...
```

So it looks like some thread local storage was allocated for the thread. It seems like a one time allocation per thread, because there are no additional allocations when I added a `pthread_create` call after the join, while there was one when I added it before the join. The `_dl_allocate_tls` suggests this is normally a functioned called during dynamic linking, but it seems it is being called during thread stack initialization. A grep through the `glibc` code shows it is being called in `allocate_stack.c`.

There does seem to be corresponding calls to `_dl_deallocate_tls` in `glibc`, so I think this error is harmless. `valgrind` does not pick up any memory leaks.

Comment: Its interesting that `valgrind` and `mtrace` see the situation differently